# Android Studio Preview is looking blurry

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout

[image: Android Studio Preview Screenshot]

Recently I bought Asus a new laptop and installed android studio. From there it started to show like this... I don't know how to solve this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess there is an opened issue about this:
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/110463869

Try:

- Go to 'Help' tab and click on 'Edit Custom Properties'. It might ask
  you to generate a file if it doesn't already exist. Once this
  properties file was made, I wrote 'hidpi=false' (no quotations) on a
  new line, saved it, and restarted Android Studio.

Even thought the issue is declared as FIXED, there are comments that they have seen this issue again in Android Studio Arctic Fox, unfortunately.